# how to set sentry timezone?

Tags: python, django, datetime, server, sentry

I am getting this `Feb 21, 2017 1:55:04 AM UTC` showing in `sentry.io` but then I want the timezone showing America/Vancouver so the issue showing in sentry.io would match my timezone correctly.

But somehow I don't seem to find anywhere to set this timezone.
I thought it was using the server timezone so I set the timezone on server to `America/Vancouver` already but still no luck.

Can someone please give me a hand?

Answer (score 6):

In Sentry 9, the timezone setting is now under [User Settings > Account Details](https://sentry.io/settings/account/details). After changing this, you do have to reload the issues page in your browser in order for the new times to be reflected.

[image]

As of this writing, they haven't yet updated their documentation to reflect this change, but for future reference: "[How can I change the timezone in Sentry?](https://help.sentry.io/hc/en-us/articles/115006562707-How-can-I-change-the-timezone-in-Sentry-)".

Comment: If the time shown does not update even after updating the timezone in sentry, make sure you do a hard refresh on the browser. `Ctrl + Shift + R`.  The time will now be updated. Just adding this comment for anyone else who might have faced this issue apart from me.

Answer (score 4):

you can set the sentry time zone by going to Account Settings -> Appearance as depicted in below picture.

[image]